# Python - Unexpected behaviour when accessing variable inside function that is defined outside function

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, scope

This results in `UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'ans' where it is not associated with a value`.

```
def a():
    ans = 4
    
    def traverse():
        if ans == 2:
            pass
        
        if True:
            ans = 3

    traverse()
    print(ans)
    
a()
```

This prints out 4:

```
def a():
    ans = 4
    
    def traverse():
        if ans == 2:
            pass

    traverse()
    print(ans)
    
a()
```

Why is it that in the second code there is no error on the `ans == 2` line but in the first case there is?

Comment: Python assumes that any variable that you assign to is a local variable.  So in the first example, `ans` is a local variable to `traverse`.  In the second function, you never assign to `ans`, so Python knows it isn't local.  Note that Python finds *all* assignments before executing, so the fact that the assignment to `ans` occurs after its value is read is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, `ans` is declared as a local variable within `traverse`, but because that's after the first time it's accessed, you get an error:

```
    def traverse():
        if ans == 2: # no local 'ans' exists yet!
            pass
        
        if True:
            ans = 3  # ans is a local var
```

In the second example, there is no assignment to `ans` inside of `traverse`, so the variable from the outer scope is used instead:

```
    def traverse():
        if ans == 2:  # 'ans' refers to the outer scope
            pass
```

What you *might* want to do is declare that `ans` is `nonlocal`, so that the assignment modifies the nonlocal var rather than creating a new var in the local scope:

```
def a():
    ans = 4
    
    def traverse():
        nonlocal ans

        if ans == 2: # accesses nonlocal ans
            pass
        
        if True:
            ans = 3  # rebinds nonlocal ans

    traverse()
    print(ans)  # prints 3
    
a()
```

Comment: In the first example, when we just enter the `traverse()` function, python has already checked that there will be an `ans` local variable but since it is not defined yet at `ans == 2` it returns an error? Why does python assume that the if branch which defines `ans = 3` will be reached. If we replace `if True` with `if False`, it still gets an error?


I assumed that python wouldn't have any idea about the local `ans` variable until it reached that line but that doesn't seem to be the case? So is there is some sort of pre-computation going on that Python does to find all assigned variables?

Comment: Yes, the code gets compiled before it actually gets executed.  Python doesn't assume that the branch will be reached, nor will it assume that it won't be reached.  That makes it simple to understand.  If there is *any* assignment to a variable within a function, even if it hasn't happened yet, and even if it *won't* happen, the name is now bound to a local variable (unless you use something like `nonlocal` to say otherwise).